# Text before an RTF table causes first table cell to be empty

Tags: c#, rtf, lync

In C# I am creating RTF strings manually. These are later sent as Persistent Chat messages via the Microsoft Lync SDK. I don't have a lot of control or insight into how the Lync servers process these messages before displaying in a client. It is possible that something is happening inside their black box, but I am trying to cover all my bases.

I am trying to create a table which has some text before it. Ideally, it might look something like this (I don't have the rep to post three images so I just wrote what it might look like in HTML):

```css
table, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
text
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>c1</td>
    <td>c2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However, if I have text before the table, the first cell is always empty. With the following code:

```
string message = @"{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{text}\trowd{c1}\intbl\cell{c2}\intbl\cell\row}";
```

I will get this result in the client:

[Undesirable Result - First Cell Empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKzdx.png)

If I just take out the text at the beginning the table will appear as desired. Code:

```
string message = @"{\rtf1\ansi\deff0\trowd{c1}\intbl\cell{c2}\intbl\cell\row}";
```

Result in client:

[Desirable Table Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mk1bM.png)

I have tried many variations of the above code. I have had a hell of a time searching this via the interwebs. I will also admit that I am brand new to RTF. Unfortunately, Persistent Chat only supports the Lync SDK which only supports plaintext or RTF.

If anyone could provide insight or direct me where to look for an explanation of this behavior, I would greatly appreciate it. If more information is needed please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viewing your example RTF in WordPad shows the same effect, so it isn't Lync specific. Starting from your example I edited the text in WordPad to replace the missing cell and saved it so I could see how the RTF had changed. The main difference appeared to be the insertion of `\par` between the text and the table.

Try this:

```
string message = @"{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{text}\par\trowd{c1}\intbl\cell{c2}\intbl\cell\row}";
```